# Each first add class js

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, each

I need to add class to every first `.event` and style it.

```js
$('.day.event')
  .first()
  .css('background-image', 'linear-gradient(145deg, #bee5ff 50%, #ffd2da 50%)');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="day">27</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">28</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">29</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">30</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">1</span></td>
    <td><span class="day event">2</span></td>
    <td><span class="day event">3</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="day">4</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">5</span></td>
    <td><span class="day event">6</span></td>
    <td><span class="day event">7</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">8</span></td>
    <td><span class="day event">9</span></td>
    <td><span class="day event">10</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please explain 1. What does the code do? 2. What you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$('tr').find('.event:first').css(....
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('tr').find('.event:first').css('background-image', 'linear-gradient(145deg, #bee5ff 50%, #ffd2da 50%)');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td><span class="day">27</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">28</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">29</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">30</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">1</span></td>
    <td><span class="day event">2</span></td>
    <td><span class="day event">3</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span class="day">4</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">5</span></td>
    <td><span class="day event">6</span></td>
    <td><span class="day event">7</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">8</span></td>
    <td><span class="day event">9</span></td>
    <td><span class="day event">10</span></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```js
$('tr').find('.day.event:first').each(function() {
  $(this)
    .css('background-image', 'linear-gradient(145deg, #bee5ff 50%, #ffd2da 50%)');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="day">27</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">28</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">29</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">30</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">1</span></td>
    <td><span class="day event">2</span></td>
    <td><span class="day event">3</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="day">4</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">5</span></td>
    <td><span class="day event">6</span></td>
    <td><span class="day event">7</span></td>
    <td><span class="day">8</span></td>
    <td><span class="day event">9</span></td>
    <td><span class="day event">10</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```